# Is it possible to directly integrate a vector function dependent on its magnitude?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Is it possible to integrate:
$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{-k\mathbf{r}}{\mid r\mid ^3}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}?$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\nabla \left( \frac{1}{|{\bf r}|}\right) = -\frac{{\bf r}}{|{\bf r}|^3}
$$

So that the *line* integral over the path $\gamma$

$$
-k \int_\gamma{\rm d}{\bf r}\cdot\frac{{\bf r}}{|{\bf r}|^3} = k\int_\gamma{\rm d}{\bf r}\cdot \nabla \left( \frac{1}{|{\bf r}|}\right) = k\int_\gamma{\rm d} \left( \frac{1}{|{\bf r}|}\right)
$$